# How to simply "recycle/reboot" running tasks in AWS ECS with no change in image/source-code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have simple query : what is the best way to simply recycle/reboot a service having 2 tasks using AWS ECS console without any actual change being deployed ?

Currently I need to update service and set tasks count from 2 to 0 and wait for tasks to drain out. Then I will set tasks count from 0 to 2 to bring it up. This is how recycle/reboot 2 tasks of a service.

I need to do this sometimes due to internal app error and just want to reboot them without any actual change which resolves my problem.

AWS provides one option (Force new deployment checkbox) which is not helping and it works if there is a change in image ? ***Wish AWS could provide one option as "Recycle a service(tasks)" which will start 2 new tasks and drain out 2 existing tasks.***

What could be the best and **easiest** way do it using AWS Console or even AWS API/CLI ?

Answer (score 1):

If you stop the tasks, ECS will launch new ones to satisfy the desired count. That's fairly easy in the ECS console, just select the tasks in the list of tasks and choose Stop in the Action dropdown.

Using the aws CLI you can get a list of the tasks to kill using:

`aws ecs list-tasks --service-name my-service`

to delete each task use:

`aws ecs stop-task --task %1`

where %1 is the ARN of the task as provided by the first command.

Here is a command that combines both commands above. It will kill all the tasks of a given service:

```
SVC=your-service-name-here
aws ecs list-tasks --service-name $SVC --output text | cut -f2 | perl -ne 'system("aws ecs stop-task --task $_")'
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, Please correct me if I am wrong. Stopping a task would kill the task right ? I need a solution where something happens in rollover fashion where existing tasks are drained and replaced with new tasks of same image. Sorry if I have not been clear in my question. Could you please advise ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, stopping will first send a SIGTERM and then eventually a SIGKILL if it doesn't self-terminate. So with this approach you will not have any tasks running for a short period of time.

Comment: To avoid service downtime, there are 2 proper approaches.

1. Create a new revision of the task definition and then update the service to use the new task revision. Then ECS will take care of the rolling upgrade for you based on the minimum and maximum health percentages assigned to your service.

2. Increase the number of desired task instances, wait for the deployment to complete, then set it back to the original value. When decreasing the number of tasks, ECS will terminate the oldest ones.